# To perform JSON-to-JSON Transformation in Azure Logic Apps Liquid Map with more than one input JSON sources

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

am exploring Liquid Transformation maps which Azure Logic Apps (Standard) offers to see if more than one JSON sources can be fed into one map to transform a single JSON response. As per Azure Documentation, I think its possible to transform JSON-to-JSON from only one JSON source.

How to achieve liquid map transformation from multiple JSON sources as input in Azure Logic App?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you can't then why not do it in two steps?  Is that an option?

Answer (score 0):

*For JSON - JSON transform you can use [JOLT](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) transformation library*

> Jolt :

> - provides a set of transforms, that can be "chained" together to form the overall JSON to JSON transform.
> - focuses on transforming the  *structure*  of your JSON data, not manipulating specific values
>
>   - The idea being: use Jolt to get most of the structure right, then write code to fix values
> - consumes and produces "hydrated" JSON : in-memory tree of Maps, Lists, Strings, etc.
>
>   - use Jackson (or whatever) to serialize and deserialize the JSON text